# Jquery tabs cookie use existing script

Tags: jquery, cookies, tabs, refresh

May be this is not so hard to do but no from JS background so hard to understand for me. I am trying to store selected tab in cookie so if page refreshed still it will display selected tab earlier.

I am already using list grid layout for my website and also have cookie set and works fine. I am posting cookie code I am using for that as well as my tabs html and javascript too.

**List/Grid Cookie JS**

```
    $(function() {
        var cc = $.cookie('list_grid');
        if (cc == 'g') {
            $('#listgrid').addClass('grid');
            $('#grid').addClass('current');            
        } else {
            $('#listgrid').removeClass('grid');
            $('#list').addClass('current');
        }
    });

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#grid').click(function() {
        $(".current").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");

        $('#listgrid').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).addClass('grid').fadeIn(500);
            $.cookie('list_grid', 'g');
        });
        return false;
    });

    $('#list').click(function() {
        $(".current").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");

        $('#listgrid').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('grid').fadeIn(500);
            $.cookie('list_grid', null);
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

**My Tabs HTML**

Tab 1

Tab 2

Tab 3

```
<div class="tabs">

    <div id="tab1" class="tab">
    </div>

    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
    </div>

    <div id="tab3" class="tab">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Tabs JS**
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        //if this is not the first tab, hide it
        jQuery(".tab:not(:first)").hide();

```
    //to fix u know who
    jQuery(".tab:first").show();

    //when we click one of the tabs
    jQuery(".htabs a").click(function () {

        $(".current").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");

        //get the ID of the element we need to show
        stringref = jQuery(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];
        //hide the tabs that doesn't match the ID
        jQuery('.tab:not(#' + stringref + ')').hide();
        //fix
        if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substr(0, 3) == "6.0") {
            jQuery('.tab#' + stringref).show();
        } else
        //display our tab fading it in
        jQuery('.tab#' + stringref).fadeIn();
        //stay with me
        return false;

    });

});
```

So can anyone please help me to do this.

Comment: are you trying to write your own tabs or use existing jQuery UI?

Comment: What I want to do is, I am using one cookie script downloaded from any tutorial for List / Grid layout. see http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/series/list-grid-view-jquery-cookies.html so I want to use same cookie script for my Tabs UI. I dont know either its possible or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your better off using the jquery ui tabs for [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#cookie)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 

// get the cookie
 var tabcookie = $.cookie('tab');    
 if (tabcookie){
     jQuery('.tab:not(#' + tabcookie + ')').hide();
     jQuery('.tab#' + tabcookie ).show();    
 }else{
      jQuery(".tab:not(:first)").hide();

    //to fix u know who
    jQuery(".tab:first").show();
 }


//when we click one of the tabs
jQuery(".htabs a").click(function () {

    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");

    //get the ID of the element we need to show
    stringref = jQuery(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];        
    //hide the tabs that doesn't match the ID
    jQuery('.tab:not(#' + stringref + ')').hide();

    // save the cookie
    $.cookie('tab', stringref);


    //fix
    if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substr(0, 3) == "6.0") {
        jQuery('.tab#' + stringref).show();
    } else
    //display our tab fading it in
    jQuery('.tab#' + stringref).fadeIn();
    //stay with me
    return false;

});
```

});​

Comment: I have tried this but somehow it didnt work as HTML markup is bit different than my one.

Comment: I have tried your code but its not even hiding my div all div display at the same time :( If you want I can give you my all files if you can find something my fault.

Comment: I think you are close, I just wanted to show that you should save the tab # in a cookie (i named 'tab') on the tab click event.  Then you can reference that cookie on the document load (jQuery(document).ready) to decide which tab you are going to show.

Comment: Dave I appreciate your help and effort but I am not form Javascript field so its going over the head. I need some specific help if you can do I would really thankful.

Comment: I put my solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddyer/HHFyu/embedded/result/).  Make sure you have a reference to the jquery cookie plug in.  ( i assume you do because you are using it in grid/list example.

Comment: Yes David I have already refer existing jquery cookie plugin script. I mean its been loading into head tag before this tab js. Again try and not working. All div display at once. I am doing something wrong may be but unable to find.

Comment: Did the link in my previous post work for you? [http://jsfiddle.net/ddyer/HHFyu/embedded/result/](http://jsfiddle.net/ddyer/HHFyu/embedded/result/)

Comment: This is wondering me why this script doesn't work with my code where you have done with the same structure and plugin. I even tried to put entire your js and check but that also didn't work.. Can any other script override or conflict to this?

Comment: Alright at last I got it work but now only problem is not storing the current state for the selected tab. It is keeping selected div open and doesn't jump back to first.

Any clue to keep current state selected. Just for your information I have current class on my first li > a so as soon as it will load first time will show first tab selected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9420/discussion-between-dave-d-and-pixelngrain)

Comment: David here we go as you said to me in chat to add ` jQuery(".htabs a:first").removeClass("current"); 
  jQuery(".htabs a:[href='#" + tabcookie + "']").addClass("current");` and it is now working completely fine.. millions thanks to you David for your great and instant help..